# Mapping a custom variable in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do I use a custom variable in a Json schema mapping? I am currently getting an error:

```
JSON path @variables('myVariable01') is invalid.
```

Comment: Hi,how you configure the json of your mapping schema?Could you please post it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like

```
@activity('GetConfigurations').output.value[0].clientId
```

Where  clientId is in your json

```
{
  "clientId": "abc"
}
```

And GetConfigurations is a lookup activity to read your settings file.